# What is the lifecycle of a fragment when replace() is called?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a number of fragments which are dynamically added using the following code:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if(position == 0){
        fragment = new FirstFragment();
    }
    else if(position == 1){
        fragment = new SecondFragment();
    }
    else if(position == 2){
        fragment = new ThirdFragment();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mCalculatorTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

In one of my fragments I have a timer and I've just discovered that when the fragment is replaced the timer in the old fragment is still running. Where in my fragment's lifecycle should I kill the timer?

EDIT:

Okay so I added a timer.cancel() in the fragment's onStop() method but onStop() also gets called when I load the preferences from a button on the action bar. This is not the desired effect. Any other ideas?

Comment: Check out - https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/02/27/fragment-lifecycle-during-fragment-transaction/ ..It explains fragment lifecycle during fragment transaction with latest appcompat version

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would kill any timers or Async work in `onStop()`

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

Quoting the API doc:

> **Stopped**
>       The fragment is not visible. Either the host activity has been stopped or the fragment has been removed from the activity but added
>   to the back stack. A stopped fragment is still alive (all state and
>   member information is retained by the system). However, it is no
>   longer visible to the user and will be killed if the activity is
>   killed.

**Fragment lifecycle:**

[image: Fragment lifecycle]

Comment: Okay this seems to correlate with what's happening but is there anything that gets called when the fragment is replaced within the same activity?

Comment: All of those should be called when a fragment is replaced.  One way to demonstrate this is to override each life-cycle method and `Log` them.  Then you can watch the various callbacks. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry I didn't ask the right question. Is there anything that gets called ONLY when the fragment is replaced? I am also loading the preferences activity on top and I don't really want the timer to stop during this time. onStop() gets called however.

Comment: Nothing specific to `replace()`, no.  But you can create your own interface called `Replaceable` with a method `onReplace()` that you have your fragment implement, and call it directly when you call `FragmentTransaction.replace()`.

Answer (score 2):

Timer task is not related with fragment life cycle.
You can cancel timer when you finished your job with that fragment. Fragment's onStop method is good place to do that.

```
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    timer.cancel();
}
```

Comment: This was my first thought but it's not completely right, onStop() also gets called when I add a new activity on top, see my edit.